# Homology class of the fiber.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let suppose that $E\rightarrow X$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $Y$. There exist a canonical homological class $[Y]$ for the bundle? For example, if $Y$ has dimension $n$ then there exist $[Y]\in H_n(E)$ in a canonical way? Or are there some condition for this to hold?

Indeed I would like to know this for the mapping torus. If $Y_\phi$ is the manifold obtained by the mapping torus method of the surface $\Sigma$. What is the canonical class $[\Sigma]$ in $H_2(Y_\phi)$?

Comment: The mapping torus of a surface will be 3 dimensional. In general, it won't be orientable.

Comment: What is a 'canonical homology class' for the bundle?

Comment: Indeed is what i want to know. If there exist a canonical class for the fiber in the homology of the bundle.

Comment: @YTS Define what you want a 'canonical class' to be. Otherwise my answer is no.